# Отмена последнего введенного символа в QTextEditor

Tags: qt

При разработке приложения на Qt столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия метода `setValidator()` в классе `QTextEdit`. Пришлось самому писать функцию проверки, которая выглядит следующим образом:

```
QRegExp textRegExp = QRegExp("[0-9a-fA-F]*");
QTextEdit *text = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(sender());
if (!textRegExp.exactMatch(text->toPlainText()))
    //undo the change
```

(функция является слотом, соединённым с сигналом `textChanged()` соответствующего объекта класса `QTextEdit`).
Собственно вопрос в том, что должно быть на месте комментария? Я попробовал `text->undo()`, однако это стирает вообще весь текст, в то время как мне нужно отменить только ввод последнего символа. Возможно ли это как-то сделать (не сохраняя каждый раз строку в отдельном поле)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому-то интересно, нашёл способ сделать это. Можно воспользоваться методом `deletePreviousChar()` класса `QTextCursor`.